# returning data back to the controller using get (ajax, javascript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

So I currently have a problem were I have an event listener waiting for a button to be pressed. As soon as it is pressed the controller method called update is called and then it calls the view method called input to try to get data from an html file, now I need to save the data and return it to the controller so I can save it in the model. The obvious problem that comes to mind is that if you are using ajax the view method cant have return calls since its asynchronous. How do I get around this problem? Here is basically a simple version of the code I am trying to get to work.

```
var controller{
  updateMVC:function(){
      view.Input(); 
  }
};

var model{
  save:function(id){}
};

var view{
  getInpurt:function()
  {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open("GET", "somehtmlpage.html");
      request.send();
  },

  showOutPut:function(output)
  {
      document.getElementById("toPost").textContent = output;
  }
};
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", controller.updateMVC, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback to return the data to the callee (the updateMVC function). That's how asynchronous JavaScript works in general.

Try:

```
view.getInput(function(err, data) {
   if(err) {
     // Error handling
   } else {
     // Do stuff..
   }
});
```

Make view.getInput look like this:

```
view.getInput = function(callback) {
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("GET", "somehtmlpage.html");
   request.send();

   request.onreadystatechange=function() {
     if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200) {
       callback(null, request.responseText);
     } else {
       callback(SOME_ERROR_DATA, null);
     }
   }
};
```